# HOW to set GMT of date picker ,date picker show wrong time

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

While i am setting up time Zome ,locale time zone still datepicker returning wrong time .

```
datepicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

It should display  like   2012-04-20 12:20 
but it is displaying      2012-04-20 12:02:42 + 0000

How can i set Time Zone of India to datepicker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should set your dateformatter's `Locale` like below:

```
-(void)localDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // set your formatter how you want
    NSDate * t = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[date description]];

    //[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; //you can set date format style
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"yourLocalidentifier"] autorelease]; 
    //you can reach your local identifier from here: [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]

    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:t]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For indian timezone in datepicker

**Objective C**

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = 5 * 60 * 60 + 30;
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:seconds]; // Like GMT+5:30
```

**in Swift 3**

```
let seconds: TimeInterval = 5*60*60 + 30
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int(seconds))  // Like GMT+5:30
```